# Formatting date view in jsp after returning a page because of errors in bindingresult

Tags: hibernate, date, jsp, spring-mvc, date-formatting

i have a silly question. I want to change the format of the date displayed in the form after the user input.
i got this situation:
The user insert two dates using a datepicker
[image: user input the dates]

Then if there is an error in bindingResult the same page is returned but the date is displayed like this:
[image: after the bindingresult]

I just want to display the dates in the second image like the dates in the first image. Thanks!

EDIT

this is the model that contain the date

```
@Entity
public class Booking implements Serializable {
//
private Date startDate;

private Date finishDate;
//
```

They are stored in a table through Hibernate
In the controller i have to do a conversion for the validation because of the date returned from mysql(i suppose). The one i get from db is in format like this "Sat Jul 01 00:00:00 CEST 2017", while the one i get from datepicker is in format like "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss".

```
@PostMapping("/rent")
    public ModelAndView vehicleRent(@RequestParam("id") long id, @ModelAttribute("newBooking") Booking booking, BindingResult bindingResult) throws ParseException {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        String stringStartDate = dateFormat.format(booking.getStartDate());
        Date formattedStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(stringStartDate);

        if (booking.getStartDate() != null || booking.getFinishDate() != null || booking != null) {
            for (Booking b : vehicleBookings) {
                if (formattedStartDate.before(b.getFinishDate()) || formattedStartDate.equals(b.getFinishDate())) {
                    bindingResult.rejectValue("startDate", "validation.booking.startdate.exists");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
//
```

the jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#startDate,#finishDate").datepicker();
    });
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rent" method="POST" modelAttribute="newBooking">
    <div>
        <table class="table">

            <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="${vehicle.id}"/>

            <tr>

                <td><form:label  path="startDate">Data Inizio</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" path="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" /> </td>
                <td><form:errors path="startDate" cssStyle="color: #ff0000" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label  path="finishDate">Data Fine</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="text" id="finishDate" name="finishDate" path="finishDate" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="finishDate" cssStyle="color: #ff0000" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input  type="submit" value="Invia" /> 

        <br>
        <br>

        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Torna alla Home</a>

    </div>
</form:form>
```

Comment: You will need to add a formatter to the date attributes you are using in your JSP, are you using spring?

Comment: Yes, i am using Spring and i used this in my jsp:

<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${startDate}' var="formattedDate"/>
<td><form:input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" path="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy"  value="${formattedDate}" /> </td>

But in this way the data is not showed after the return on the page

Comment: Could do you add to your question the bean are you sending to the JSP?

Comment: i added some information  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add this annotation to you bear @DateTimeFormat

```
@Entity
public class Booking implements Serializable {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    private Date finishDate;
```

Comment: It works! but if a would a date format like "dd/MM/yyyy"? I tried to use @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") but the result is "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: should works for MM/dd/yyyy check you doesnt override the format value in the jsp

Comment: i had to change the validation and apply the format in the datePicker, now it works ;) thanks!

Comment: @TroubleM great! good work, could also check the response as valid, so could be useful for other users? Thanks!